# sum if condition true, subtract if false mysqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I'm using mysqlite in my app and I'm having the following problem:
I have a table with the columns 'name', 'value' and 'condition' and I'd like to query the distinct names and the sum of the values of this name. But there's a condition: I want to sum only the names with 'condition' = 1 and I want to subtract the value if the 'condition' = 0.

Comment: Q: "Is it possible?" A: Yes. Please post a data sample and any solutions you've attempted. Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and also [StackOverflow Help Center: How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a `case` expression to do that:

```
SELECT   name, SUM(CASE condition WHEN 1 THEN value
                                  WHEN 0 THEN value * (-1))
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, SUM(((condition * 2) - 1) * value)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name
```

Notice how `(condition * 2) - 1)` evaluates to `1`, if condition is `1` and `-1` if condition is `0`, thereby producing the output you need.

Comment: This implicitly assumes that `condition` can only have `0`s and `1`s. I'm not sure if it's OK to assume this.